# Key Error when trying to format columns use variables python 3

Tags: python, format, multiple-columns, keyerror

I am trying to format a group of columns in python 3.  So far I have not had much luck.  I managed to get the columns to print, but I can't get them to line up.  I am trying to make each column dynamic so that it can adapt if different information needs to be printed.   But because I am trying to use variables in the column formatting, I keep getting Key Errors.  Any idea how I can fix this?

```
Indicator                              :Min                                   :Max                                   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/test.py", line 154, in <module>
    print('{heart:{heart_col_width}}:{motor:{motor_col_width}} {teen:{teen_col_width}{smoke:        {smoke_col_width}}{obese:{obese_col_width}'.format(heart, motor, teen, smoke, obese ))
KeyError: 'heart'
```

> > > 

This is the code I am using.

```
first_row = ['Indicator',':Min',':Max']

col_width = max(len(word) for word in first_row) +20# padding

print ("".join(word.ljust(col_width) for word in first_row))

print('----------------------------------------------------------------------------')

heart=['Heart Disease Death Rate     (2007)',stateheart_min(),heartdis_min(),stateheart_max(),heartdis_max()]
motor=[ 'Motor Vehicle Death Rate     (2009)',statemotor_min(),motordeath_min(),statemotor_max(),motordeath_max()]
teen=['Teen Birth Rate (2009)',stateteen_min(),teenbirth_min(),stateteen_max(),teenbirth_max()]
smoke=['Adult Smoking     (2010)',statesmoke_min(),adultsmoke_min(),statesmoke_max(),adultsmoke_max()]
obese=['Adult Obesity     (2010)',stateobese_min(),adultobese_min(),stateobese_max(),adultobese_max()]

heart_col_width = max(len(word) for word in heart)
motor_col_width = max(len(word) for word in motor)
teen_col_width = max(len(word) for word in teen)
smoke_col_width = max(len(word) for word in smoke)
obese_col_width = max(len(word) for word in obese)


for heart, motor, teen, smoke, obese in zip(heart, motor, teen, smoke, obese ):
    print('{heart:{heart_col_width}}:{motor:{motor_col_width}} {teen:{teen_col_width}{smoke:    {smoke_col_width}}{obese:{obese_col_width}'.format(heart, motor, teen, smoke, obese ))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
"{whatever}".format(whatever)
```

the `format` function doesn't know how to "match" or "connect" the *whatever* in `"{whatever}"` to the *whatever* in `format(whatever)` For the interpreter, they have nothing to do with each other. When the `.format` function sees the `"{whatever}"` it will try to look for a **keyword** argument `whatever` in its call, but there's none. It only knows that there's a **positional** argument (which is not the <s>droid</s>... erm... the argument that it's looking for)

You might want to understand what positional arguments are versus keyword arguments (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs) SO thread) In general, you're gonna need to know that difference very well for any Python development that you work on.

Knowing that, let's go back to the `.format` method:

You need to explicitly tell the `.format` method the connection between the two *whatevers*:

```
"{whatever}".format(whatever=whatever)
```

Maybe it's clearer by doing:

```
foo="hello"
"{whatever}".format(whatever=foo)
#   ^                 ^
#   |_________________|
```

So in your case, you can do:

```
for heart, motor, teen, smoke, obese in zip(heart, motor, teen, smoke, obese ):
    print(
        '{heart:{heart_col_width}}:{motor:{motor_col_width}}'
        ' {teen:{teen_col_width}{smoke:{smoke_col_width}}'
        ' {obese:{obese_col_width}'.format(
            heart=heart, heart_col_width=heart_col_width,
            motor=motor, motor_col_width=motor_col_width,
            teen=teen, teen_col_width=teen_col_width,
            smoke=smoke, smoke_col_width=smoke_col_width,
            obese=obese, obese_col_width=obese_col_width)
    )
```

Thanks to the use of these keyword arguments, if the column width is the same for all the columns, you don't need to re-specify it. You can just reuse them in different parts of your string:

```
heart = "hello"
motor = "goodbye"
filler = 10
print (
    "{heart:{filler}} someting something {motor:{filler}} something something"
    .format(heart=heart, motor=motor, filler=filler)
)
```

Check this [string formatting tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) (particularly its [examples section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples)). It might give you some alternative ideas.